# How to handle error on other thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, compact-framework, exception

I'm trying to handle errors that have occurred on other threads the .NET CF program is like below:

```
static void Main()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Start);
    t.Start();
    ...
}

void Start()
{
     ... Exception here

}
```

In my situation, putting try catch in the Start method is impossible. How can I handle it in the global code?

Comment: Something similar: [catching-exceptions-from-another-thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188977/catching-exceptions-from-another-thread)

Comment: Can someone with more rep than me tag this with 'exception-handling' or similar?

Comment: It's not really similar. I'm asking for a similar way that NUnit does. But the environment is now .NET CF

Comment: You should update your question then. I have replied in kind with something that describes the way NUnit does it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I have read your article. It's great. I'm curious about your product when the home page just shows the welcome message.

Comment: Glad you liked the article, hope it was useful. If you're curious as to what we're up to, please subscribe to our RSS feed for updates. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) but you cannot "recover" an application from this, the best you can do is display a message to the user and fail gracefully.

Comment: I forgot the main point is for .NET CF.

Is there any way to do like NUnit? If an error has occurred on other thread, it still keeps going.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not familiar with .Net CF.

Comment: @markattwood.If you are re'fing to the way NUnit ignores exceptions on non-test threads, please see a blog article I wrote that describes the same issue\feature with the ReSharper test runner. It's controlled by legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy. http://gojisoft.com/blog/2010/05/14/resharper-test-runner-hidden-thread-exceptions/

Comment: I have managed the Pocket Unit Test to do like NUNit now. Thanks for the AooDomain.UnhandledException tip.

Answer (score 5):

Without going into best practices in exception handling, you can use a shim method to do what you want, e.g.

```
static void Main()
{
  Thread t = new Thread(Shim);
  t.Start();
  ...
}

void Shim()
{
  try
  {
    Start();
  }
  catch
  {
    //If there's something you can really do about it...
  }
}

void Start()
{
  ... Exception here

}
```

**Update**

If you are referring to the way NUnit ignores exceptions on non-test threads, please see a blog article I wrote that describes the same issue\feature with the ReSharper test runner. It's controlled by legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy.

http://gojisoft.com/blog/2010/05/14/resharper-test-runner-hidden-thread-exceptions/

Comment: It still does not work if the Start method creates a new thread and an exception is risen inside it. I'm doing a test project for Pocket PC env and it is quite similar to NUnit.