# Process aborts with SIGABRT when a thread runs after exception is caught in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, abort

I have a exit handler thread waiting on a condition for the worker thread to do its work. The signalling is done from the worker thread's destructor.

Below is the code of the exit handler thread.

```
void Class::TaskExitHandler::run() throw()
{

while( ! isInterrupted() ) {

    _book->_eot_cond.wait(); // Waiting on this condition
    {
        CLASS_NAMESPACE::Guard<CLASS_NAMESPACE::FastLock> eguard(_book->_exitlist_lock);

        list<TaskGroupExecutor*>::const_iterator itr = _book->_exited_tasks.begin();

        for( ; itr != _book->_exited_tasks.end(); itr++ ) {
            (*itr)->join();
            TRACER(TRC_DEBUG)<< "Deleting exited task:" << (*itr)->getLoc() << ":"
                     << (*itr)->getTestID() << ":" << (*itr)->getReportName() << endl;
            delete (*itr);
        }
        _book->_exited_tasks.clear();
    }
    _book->executeAny();
}
}
}
```

Now, what has been observed is that when the worker thread catches any exception(raised from a lower layer), this thread is continued, and immediately cores with exit code 134, which is SIGABRT.

The stacktrace is as follows-

```
#0  0x0000005555f49b4c in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000005555f4b568 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000005555d848b4 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000005555d82210 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0000005555d82258 in std::terminate () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000005555d82278 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x0000005555d81b18 in __cxa_call_unexpected () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000000120047898 in Class::TaskExitHandler::run ()
#8  0x000000012001cd38 in commutil::ThreadBase::thread_proxy ()
#9  0x0000005555c6e438 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x0000005555feed6c in __thread_start () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

So it seems that this run() function which specifies that it will not throw any exceptions using "throw()" spec, raises an exception(from Frame 4). As per various references about __cxa_call_unexpected(), the stacktrace depicts the typical behaviour of compiler to abort when exception is raised in a function with "throw()" spec.
Am I right with the analysis of the problem?

To test, I added a try catch in this method, and printed the exception message. Now the process didn't core. The exception message was same as the one caught by worker thread. 
My question is, how does this thread get access to the exception caught by the other? Do they share some datastructure related to exception handling?

Please throw some light on this. It is quite puzzling..

Note:- As per stacktrace, the call_unexpected is raised immediately after run() is called. That strengthens my doubt that somehow exception stack or data is shared. But didn't find any references to this behaviour.

Comment: 'So it seems that this run() function which specifies that it will not throw any exceptions using "throw()" spec, raises an exception(from Frame 4)' Heh! If you want a job done properly, burn all the specs first!

Comment: yeah! unfortunately this class has to inherit from a common utility class, and hence the limitation. :(

Comment: Maybe both threads have thrown?  This is strange code - it almost looks like thread micromanagement..

Comment: I had introduced the try-catch to check whether/what the exit handler thread had thrown. It turned out to be the same message that the worker handler would receive. Plus, it is not raised from any of the methods invoked here, or it would have been visible in the stacktrace.

Comment: hmm. I am just thinking. both these threads are inherited from a common class, which is singleton and so on. Is there is a chance that this class maintains its stack as a static data so that all inherited classes and there objects see the same exceptions? I am just asking whether it is possible this way. If so I can dig into that code...

Comment: Yes, I'd already discounted getLoc() etc. for that reason.  This looks like some kind of double-fault where the work thread excepts, tries to destroy itself and excepts again in the dtor after signalling the condvar.  What this would do to the thread trying to wait on join() I don't know.. :((

Comment: the root cause has been identified. it turned out that in the destructor of the object pointed by *itr, the same operation is performed, and the same exception is thrown again. anyway the try-catch holds good :) the question is answered.. how do i close this??

Comment: Good question.  Maybe you could post an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall answer my own question.
What has happened in this case was there was a destructor being invoked in the TaskExitHandler thread. This destructor was performing the same operation which caused the exception in the main thread.

As the TaskExitHandler thread was designed to not throw(or rather expected), there were no try-catch blocks, and hence process aborted when the exception was raised.

As the destructor's call was implicit, it never displayed in stacktrace making it very difficult to find. Each object had to be tracked down to find this exception leakage.

Thanks everyone for the active participation :) this was my first question to get some active responses..

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab - hopefully this will give you enough to continue your research.

I suspect the thread running TaskExitHandler is the parent thread for all of the worker threads.  TEH would have a hard(er) time joining up with the children otherwise.

The child / worker threads are not handling the exceptions thrown to them.  However, an exception must be handled **somewhere** or the entire process will get shut down.  The parent thread (aka TEH) is the last stop in the process's stack / chain for handling exceptions.  Your sample code shows that TEH's exception handling is to simply throw / not handle the exception.  So it cores out.

It's not necessarily a data structure that's being shared, but rather the process / thread IDs and memory space.  The child threads do share global memory / heap space with the parent and each other, hence the need for semaphores and / or mutexes for locking purposes.

Good encapsulation dictates that the worker threads should be smart enough to handle any / all exceptions they might see.  That way, the individual worker thread can be killed off instead of bringing down the parent thread and the rest of the process tree.  OTW, you can continue catching the exception(s) in TEH, but it's really unlikely that thread has (or should have) the knowledge of what to do with the exception.

Add a comment if the above isn't clear, I'm happy to explain further.

I did a little research and confirmed that exceptions are generated against heap memory, not stack memory.  All the threads of your process share the same heap*, so it makes more sense (at least to me) why the parent thread would see the exception when the child thread doesn't catch it.  *FWIW, if you fork your process instead of starting a new thread, you'll get a new heap as well.  However, forking is an expensive operation against the memory since you're copying all the heap contents over to the new process as well.

This SO thread discusses setting up a thread to catch all exceptions, which will probably be of interest:
[catching exceptions from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188977/catching-exceptions-from-another-thread)

Comment: your explanation does make sense. but here it is not the case. I have identified the answer to my problem. you can see my above comments for the answer. But I would like to know that if one thread throws and exception , can another thread(not parent, but sibling) catch it? I am not posting a new question. The original question related to problem was same. Problem was solved,but my question not answered :)