# Catch exceptions of a thread in the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have a thread:

```
Thread mthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread_main));
mthread.Start();
```

It starts the function `thread_main`

```
void thread_main()
{
    if (BotSuite.ImageLibrary.Template.Image(screendata, invdata).IsEmpty)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

This exception  should be caught in the main thread! I added a line in the button event handler.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ErrorHandler);
```

it works great if the exception is in the main thread, but if it's in the `mthread` nothing happens!

How can I fix that?

Comment: Consider using tasks instead of threads; they can report asynchronous failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188977/catching-exceptions-from-another-thread

Comment: I have read this, but it didn't help me!
@SLaks how do I do this? I haven't really used tasks before! May you give me a short example as answer, please!

Comment: About using Task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use Backroundworker if you are using an older Visual Studio or don't want to use Tasks.

```
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += WorkerDoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    private static void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("my exception");
    }

    private static void WorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            //error handling
        }
    }
```